# Querying ravendb index using named field and collection

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I have the following index in ravendb, Changes_Which is a named field and this maps to a sub collection

```
    public My_Index()
    {
        Map = revisions => from revision in revisions
                           from change in revision.Changes
                           where (revision.AuditedType == "typeA")
                       select
                        new
                        {
                            revision.ChangeTimestamp,
                            Changes_Which = change.Which
                        };

    }
```

the json for a revision looks like:

```
{
"AuditedType" : "typeA",
"Changes": [
{
"SubWhich": null,
"Which": "Regulation",
"Original": "Unknown",
"New": "Yes"
},
{
"SubWhich": null,
"Which": "Other",
"Original": "Unknown",
"New": "Yes"
},
{
"SubWhich": null,
"Which": "Regulation",
"Original": "Unknown",
"New": "Yes"
}
]
"ChangeTimestamp": "2011-05-03"
}
```

I am trying to filter the results from the index using the Changes_Which field:

```
        var q = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<revision>("My_Index/Index")
            .WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()
            .AddOrder(paging.SortColumn, paging.SortOrder == "desc")
            .Skip(((paging.CurrentPage - 1) * paging.RecordsPerPage))
            .Take(paging.RecordsPerPage);

        if (fromDate > DateTime.MinValue && toDate > DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            q = q.WhereGreaterThanOrEqual("ChangeTimestamp", fromDate)
                .AndAlso()
                .WhereLessThanOrEqual("ChangeTimestamp", toDate.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1));
        }

        if (removeNoChange)
        {
            q = q.AndAlso().Not.WhereEquals("Changes_Which", "Regulation");  
        }
```

This line:

q = q.AndAlso().Not.WhereEquals("Changes_Which", "Regulation");

does work, but only removes the first match on "Which": "Regulation", the third one in the collection remains.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are outputting different index entries for the same document.
When searching in RavenDB, you are searching on documents, and in your case, you filtered out the first index entry on that document, but there are other index entries that match, so it is returned.

You are probably better off with:

```
 Map = revisions => from revision in revisions
                    where (revision.AuditedType == "typeA")
                    select
                    new
                    {
                        revision.ChangeTimestamp,
                        Changes_Which = revision.Changes.Select(chnage => change.Which)
                    };
```

This will output just a single entry per document (which is recommended) and will result in filtering of all documents that were changed because of `Regulation`